# Body Parse return a string body

Tags: node.js, react-native, fetch, body-parser

I have a React Native front end using a Fetch POST method, I send the body below, but on my NodeJS server on the back end I am getting all the methods as undefined, apparently the body is still as a string object, even using body parse.

```
     var requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: JSON.stringify({
            postid: 1235,
            whatsapp: this.state.whatsapp,
            telefone: this.state.telefone,
            links: toApi,
        }),

        redirect: 'follow'
    };
```

In my NodeJS server:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

[...]
app.post('/api/updateinfos', function (req, res) {
var postId = req.body.postid;
console.log(postId);

if(req.body.postid === undefined)
{
    return res.status(201).send({
    success: 'false',
    message: 'no postid',
    })
}

    var whatapp = req.body.whatsapp;
    var telefone = req.body.telefone;

    var links = req.body.links;
});
```

Using "console.log(req.body)", I'm getting:

```
'{"postid":1235,"whatsapp":"3123213","telefone":"12312312312","links":"a:1:{i:0;a:1:{s:7:\\"network\\";a:0:{}}}"}'
```

Comment: [Object: null prototype] {
  '{"postid":1235,"whatsapp":"3123213","telefone":"12312312312","links":"a:1:{i:0;a:1:{s:7:\\"network\\";a:0:{}}}"}': ''
}

Comment: Are you passing Content-Type in header ?
Content-Type: application/json

Answer (score 0):

I very recently started working with node.js and express.js but in the course I am in they have us always set the extended true. So I would try that I know it may not be much help but I wanted to pass it along when I saw this looking for another answer.

What you have:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
```

What I would try:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
```

Hope it helps!